# How to combine multiple rows in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2012: I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE simpletable 
( 
     [key] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
     [id] INT, 
     [ca] INT, 
     [cp] INT, 
     [ct] INT
)
```

For various reasons this table only has a single row per [ca], [cp] and [ct] - like this:

```
INSERT INTO simpletable ([id], [ca], [cp], [ct])
VALUES (1, 10, null, null),
       (1, null, 20, null),
       (1, null, 120, null),
       (1, null, null, 30),
       (2, 11, null, null),
       (2, null, 21, null),
       (2, null, null, 31),
       (2, null, null, 231)
```

What I would like to achieve (without cursors) is to explode out all the combinations into a temp table or a table-type variable; something like this:

```
id  ca  cp  ct
---------------
1   10  20  30
1   10  120 30
2   11  21  31
2   11  21  231
```

I'd really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: That's the *opposite* of expanding. You are combining multiple rows into fewer ones

Comment: Your gripe is with the title? OK, I changed it, how about helping with the answer?

Comment: It's not a gripe. It means that you are looking for the wrong thing (expansion). You should be looking for ways to *reduce* the rows. You could use any aggregation function for example to remove NULLs if there weren't rows with multiple values per ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one (Cumbersome) way to do it:

```
SELECT dca.[id], dca.[ca], dcp.[cp], dct.[ct]
FROM 
(
    SELECT [id], [ca]
    FROM simpletable
    WHERE [ca] IS NOT NULL
) dca 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT [id], [cp]
    FROM simpletable
    WHERE [cp] IS NOT NULL
) dcp ON dca.id = dcp.id

INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT [id], [ct]
    FROM simpletable
    WHERE [ct] IS NOT NULL
) dct ON dca.id = dct.id
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/RZQ79441)

**Note** this solution is based on the assumption that there must be at least one column other then `id` that is not null in every row.

Comment: thanks, I spent sometime yesterday trying to use PIVOT but for some reason this solution never came to mind!!

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)